# Wordpress - Opcode-кеш и лимиты памяти

Tags: php, wordpress, кэширование

Хотелось бы уточнить следующие моменты:

Есть ли лимит максимального размера у Opcode-кеша и как его узнать? (помимо вопроса в поддержку хостинга). Можно ли изменить его через `php.ini`?

Если на хостинге с максимальной оперативной памятью 256МБ, я задам максимальный размер памяти под Wordpress 256МБ и так случится, что он однажды 'загрузит' все, то на кеш не останется памяти, верно?

Если на предыдущие вопросы ответ '**да**', то есть еще вопрос: Какое соотношение "Память под Wordpress : Память под кеш" лучше взять? Сайт небольшой, плагинов штук 20 (SEO, WP Total Cache и прочие 'стандартные')

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите в сторону `opcache_get_configuration()`. Практически все можно поменять через php.ini.

Лимит необходимо ставить не более 30%, так как память расходуется и на сам движок и на плагины и прочие накладные расходы. Делается это, как вы и заметили, чтобы сайт не "лёг" отдохнуть.